# printf skips first character of character array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, character

In the code given below, I am trying to take string input using **scanf** in **while** loop. When I print that string, it is printed without the first character. But it prints correctly when I copy it in another string and print that new string.

In my code, if I give **"abc"** as input and print both strings, then **"bc abc"** is printed instead of **"abc abc"**.

What is the reason for this? Is something wrong in my code?

```
int main()
{
    char st1[10],st2[]="";
    while(scanf("%s",st1)==1){
        strcpy(st2,st1);
        printf("%s %s\n",st1,st2);
        strcpy(st2,"");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `st2[]=""` is probably meaninless.

Comment: Is it C or C++?

Comment: Ohh! Can you explain why it is working right after using "st2[10]" instead? @SouravGhosh

Comment: it is c++ @tilz0R

Comment: @SadmanRizwan updated answer.

Comment: It's already explained in the dupe linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

`char st1[10],st2[]="";` reserves 10 bytes for `st1` and 1 byte for `st2`.

Then you are trying to copy content of st1 to st2.

Remove this as it is not required:

```
strcpy(st2,"");
```

Change this:

```
char st1[10],st2[10];
```

Now you have memory for both variables and you can copy data between. In first example you did not have reserved enough memory for `st2` variable and behaviour was in general undefined.